How to assign 'Glow' in 4.2 to only few objects?
For Blender 4.2, to add Glow I need to add 'Glare' in the scene node, and it works but taking everything in the scene.
I need this to only be applied to a few objects. How can I achieve this?
Greetings and thank you very much in advance.



Hello, in this particular case it's a screen space effect so unless you use a mask using cryptomatte or a setup of view layers I don't think you can select which objects are affected by it. Or do you mean you only want some light sources to cause glow ? Please elaborate :)

To be honest, I'm just learning how to render by passes, I think that more than an object can be applied to a complete 'collection', but for that I would need to know how to render things separately, or at least that 'Glare' effect since I only want it on some objects, and not all. I know I could get 2 renders separately, but I imagine that thanks to the passes I could get just one with this included. Or am I wrong? Thank you very much for being understanding.
